# Using full path vs relative paths with AJAX

Tags: ajax, http

I am currently implementing a feature that will allow a site admin to configure AJAX paths as either relative to root or as the full URL (`protocol://host/path`). The one thing that I am not sure of is the performance implications.

My gut tells me that using a full URL would introduce some additional overhead that you wouldn't find with a relative path; however, I really don't know.

My main concern (outside of usability) for this application is the server response time to AJAX requests, as I am using AngularJS heavily to manipulate the dom (and a few of the backend models are a bit expensive).

**Are any differences in performance between the two methods going to be significant enough for me to worry about?**

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance implication. Actually, a relative url is converted into an absolute url by the browser (nearly instantaneously) to allow it to be used to find exactly who to talk to. Neither of these will be noticeable, even on a millisecond level.

99.9999% of the time will be waiting for the server to respond.